# User with suspension has different reputation on SO and MSO

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, reputation-history, reputation-graph

[One account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70345/ian-kemp?tab=profile) on MSO and normal SO has one reputation point (they are suspended), however with this account, there is something wrong. The once-reached reputation is different on MSO and SO. Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you read the outlined banner at the top of the page???

Comment: Suspended user's rep drops to 1 while the suspension lasts.

Comment: "The once-reached reputation is different on MSO and SO." What do you mean? I see the user displayed as 1 reputation on both sites. On SO I see a graph of reputation history indicating the base reputation before suspension, but no number associated with this. On MSO I see **no graph** - which is **the same as for non-suspended users**.

Comment: My money is on caching